# Power analysis of a chunk test

Tags: r, regression, anova, f-test, f-statistic

I set up following chunk test in R:

```
restricted Model <- DV ~ IV1
unrestricted Model <- DV ~ IV1 + IV2 + IV3
anova(restricted Model, unrestricted Model)
```

Whereas IV1, IV2, and IV3 are all categorical variables with many levels.

I would like to analyze the power of my test. Which test/analyzing tool is the correct choice?

Comment: Nice question +1. I expect the issue I discuss [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/597693/247274) to play a role.